# CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptors in Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Phone app I used `CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptors` to sort my `LongListSelector`s  content. Now I migrated to Windows Runtime app and am using `ListView` to display my content. (And WinRT doesn't have `SortDescriptors`.)

Using `OrderBy<>()` on my `ObserveableCollection` is not an option, since I add the items dynamically (and this would cause a complete reload of the `ListView`).

**How do I "binary insert" on `ObservableCollection` (similar to what's possible with `List<>`) or is there any alternative to `CollectionViewSource`.**

Comment: `CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptors` Oh, if only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this [A winRT CollectionView with filtering and sorting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/527686/A-WinRT-CollectionView-class-with-Filtering-and-So)

Alternatively you could create a class and override ObservableCollection.InsertItem like this.

```
public class SortedCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        int sortedIndex = FindSortedIndex(item);
        base.InsertItem(sortedIndex, item);
    }

    private int FindSortedIndex(T item)
    {
        //simple sorting algorithm
        for (int index = 0; index < this.Count; index++)
        {
            if (item.CompareTo(this[index]) > 0)
            {
                return index;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

To use this class create a new collection and add the items.

```
SortedCollection<int> sortedCollection = new SortedCollection<int>();
sortedCollection.Add(3);
sortedCollection.Add(1);
sortedCollection.Add(5);
sortedCollection.Add(4);
sortedCollection.Add(2);
//the sorted collection will be 1,2,3,4,5
```